# Bug with new Firefox version and standard Qooxdoo widgets

Tags: firefox, qooxdoo

Problem appear with my Firefox 65.0.1 installed.
Go to any Qooxdoo demo, try a combobox or selectbox, try to use arrows keys to select dropdown list items, or Esc key to close dropdown list.
With Firefox don't work.
(sorry my english!)